# UserId string comparison within ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET identity in MVC 5 and wondered the best way to perform string comparison during say, a query to a table where records have been entered with the userId as an foreign key.

Normally I would just plump for `==` but I wasn't sure how the string for a userId inside .NET identity is created. 
I guess it's actually a GUID of sorts under the hood so I'd presume that `==` would be fine but I wondered if the culture or case would come into it at all.

Does anyone know if the string is a unique GUID for `==` type comparison, or should I be using `string.Equals` and some `StringComparison` option to account for cultures?

Comment: Identity uses strings for user Id by default, have you changed it?

Comment: I've not changed anything, it's a string as I specified

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Identity can use GUID for keys. In that case GUID should not have any culture specific characters. So `StringComparision.   InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` should go for `string.Equals` in C#. `ToLower` (`ToUpper`) can be used for SQL queries (LINQ).

Comment: It can use a GUID, but mine is the same as it was by default and it just a string.

Comment: It should be GUID stored as string by default (not `System.Guid` structure). Check out [this code](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUser.cs). It is `Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm getting at it's a GUID, so it shouldn't be culture specific right? but then during the ToString() call 'could' it be influenced by server culture in a way which would cause me issues, or is a plan '==' going to cut the mustard?

Comment: Not sure I understand the fear. Guid is presented as hexadecimal digits. Not sure I understand the fear: no culture specific chars, I repeat. The `==` way, which goes as [`String.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is case-sensitive. So the above solutions proposed.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering whether by ignoring case, that I might get a duplicate (if it is a GUID as described and the alphabetic chars HEX, then it's fine as you say). Or alternatively that if say I make the assumption that case doesn't matter, that if I recall a value from the db in upper case but the .NET code under some conditions, like x64 vs x86 decides to flip to lower case that a case sensitive comparison will not match when I'm expecting it to.

Comment: This fear is probably because I recently had > 100 unit tests fail when our build server picked a different agent and decided that it would behave differently in different architectures. I'd used a case sensitive comparison for windows authentication usernames which caused the issue.

Comment: Strange to hear that two calls to methods (`ToUpper` or `ToLower`) or the different call to `String.Equals` makes you question this. While this is not an optimization as seen it is even more strange.

Comment: [`Guid.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should return lowercase as per doc. I recommend to add a check (CodeContracts or other) on persisting if you wish not to consider case. If this is guid [using `TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and if all are in lower case. So the answer given suits?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Ordinal/OrdinalIgnoreCase StringComparisons here as it compares strings character by character without regard to linguistic convention.

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx

And here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx

Code samples:

```
string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```